# Find all elements with regex of a datatable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, datatable

I have a data table that has a structure like:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>ABC<td>
    <td id="invNumbers0">DEF<td>
</tr>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>GHI<td>
    <td id="invNumbers1">JKL<td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>MNO<td>
    <td id="invNumbers2">PQR<td>
</tr>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>STU<td>
    <td id="invNumbers3">WXY<td>
</tr>
```

I want to find the count of  whose id starts with "invNumbers"

I have tried using below code and it is giving empty results

```
var table = $('#result').DataTable();
        $('#result').on( 'page.dt', function () {
            var uniInv = 0;
            alert( 'Table redrawn' );

            if(!isEmpty($('#result').find('$([id^="invnumbers"]').val())){
                uniInv++;
            }
            alert(uniInv);
        });
```

Comment: Simply use `$('#result').find('[id^="invNumbers"]').length`

Comment: Thanks it worked. I tried retrieving their values using alert($('#result').find('[id^="invNumbers"]').value); and alert($('#result').find('[id^="invNumbers"]').val()); But i am getting the results as undefined. Could you please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `$().length`?
exmaple:

```
alert($('[id^=invNumbers]').length);
```

fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mof3497u/

Comment: Thanks.How can I find their values ? I have tried alert($('[id^=invNumbers]').value);
alert($('[id^=invNumbers]').val());

Comment: @Anurag1804 Accept this answer and create a different question.

Comment: Accepted and the new question is:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63736246/getting-the-value-from-a-regex-element-id-in-jquery-datatable