# Getting the value from a regex element id in jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a data table that has a structure like:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>ABC<td>
    <td id="invNumbers0">DEF<td>
</tr>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>GHI<td>
    <td id="invNumbers1">JKL<td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>MNO<td>
    <td id="invNumbers2">PQR<td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>STU<td>
    <td id="invNumbers3">WXY<td>
</tr>
```

I want to find the value of all the elements whose id starts with "invNumbers"

I have tried:

```
alert($('[id^=invNumbers]').value);
alert($('[id^=invNumbers]').val());
```

Comment: Your `td` are not closed, second you need to use `.text()` not `.val()`

Comment: Yeah that worked but they are not a comma or separated by a delimiter (space would also do). Can you please help @AlwaysHelping

Comment: @Anurag1804 Sure no worries  - See my updated answer. All of text with matched `id'` is showing separately.

Comment: Thanks man. You truly justified your user name. Thanks a lot @AlwaysHelping

Comment: @Anurag1804 You are welcome - Happy to help always.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping : Is there any inbuilt function which can tell me the count of unique elements present  in this list, because i was thinking to sort it first and then remove duplicates and then find the count of unique. Sorry, if that sounds silly I am new to UI .

Comment: @Anurag1804 Sure. In your current demo table you do not have duplicate at all. But in real scenarios you would use `.remove` function delete duplicate data from your table. Ideally if you can post another with real table data then its easier to understand on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping : I have posted the whole problem in a new question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63737350/getting-the-count-of-unique-values-for-elements-with-regex-in-datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `table` HTML structure is currently **not** valid as you need to enclosed `tbody's` within the `table` and you are missing closing tags of `td's` as well.

In addition, to get the `text` whose `id` starts with "invNumbers" you need to use jQuery [.text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/) function not `.val()`

**Edit:** Since you want them separated by `space` or `commas`. Ideally in that case you can use `.each` function to get each of `text` separately so that you can do whatever you want with each text individually.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
$('[id^=invNumbers]').each(function(x, o) {
  console.log($(o).text()) //showing each id text seperately
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>ABC</td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="invNumbers0">DEF</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>GHI</td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="invNumbers1">JKL</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>MNO</td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="invNumbers2">PQR</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>STU</td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="invNumbers3">WXY</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```