# Getting the count of unique values for elements with regex in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a data table that has a structure like:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>ABC</td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="invNumbers0">12345</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>GHI</td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="invNumbers1">12345</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>MNO</td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="invNumbers2">4566</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>STU</td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="invNumbers3">12345</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ABC</td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="invNumbers4">2566</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>GHI</td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="invNumbers5">4566"</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>MNO</td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="invNumbers6">12345</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>STU</td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="invNumbers7">12345</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to have the count of the unique values present in the elements with id starting from "invNumbers".
Duplicate values should be only counted once. So here the output should be
Count = 3 . As I have only 3 unique values i.e. 12345,4566,2566.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 3 versions

- ES6 with fat arrows
- ES2015 with function
- Legacy JS which should run from IE8 or so

```js
const uniqueCount = [...document.querySelectorAll("td[id^=invNumbers]")]
  .reduce((acc, cur) => {
    const val = cur.textContent;
    if (!acc.includes(val)) acc.push(val);
    return acc;
  }, []).length;
console.log(uniqueCount)

// no fat arrows =>

const uniqueCount1 = [...document.querySelectorAll("td[id^=invNumbers]")]
  .reduce(function(acc, cur) {
    const val = cur.textContent;
    if (!acc.includes(val)) acc.push(val);
    return acc;
  }, []).length;
console.log(uniqueCount1)


// Legacy  - not ES2015 or ES6

var cells = document.querySelectorAll("td[id^=invNumbers]"); // supported since IE9 or so
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
  var val = cells[i].innerText;
  if (arr.indexOf(val) ===-1) arr.push(val);
}
console.log(arr.length)
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>ABC</td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="invNumbers0">12345</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>GHI</td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="invNumbers1">12345</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>MNO</td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="invNumbers2">4566</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>STU</td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="invNumbers3">12345</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ABC</td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="invNumbers4">2566</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>GHI</td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="invNumbers5">4566</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>MNO</td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="invNumbers6">12345</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>STU</td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="invNumbers7">12345</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yeah it works well but i can use "=>" operator. I am working on some legacy application that does not support this operator

Comment: I have updated my code and removed value attribute from <td>

Comment: See update. You had a loose " after one number so the counter was 4, I have removed the "

Comment: I have added a function without fat arrow AND one with legacy JavaScript

Comment: Which one could you use, 2 or 3?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var arr = $('td[id^=invNumbers]').map(function() {
  return $(this).text()
}).get();
var unique = arr.filter(function(v, i, a) {
  return a.indexOf(v) === i
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = $('td[id^=invNumbers]').map(function() {
  return $(this).text()
}).get();
var unique = arr.filter(function(v, i, a) {
  return a.indexOf(v) === i
});
console.log(unique);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>ABC</td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="invNumbers0">12345</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>GHI</td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="invNumbers1">12345</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>MNO</td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="invNumbers2">4566</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>STU</td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="invNumbers3">12345</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ABC</td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="invNumbers4">2566</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>GHI</td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="invNumbers5">4566</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>MNO</td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="invNumbers6">12345</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>STU</td>
      <td></td>
      <td id="invNumbers7">12345</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yeah it works well but i can use "=>" operator. I am working on some legacy application that does not support this operator

Comment: @Its there in the next line:
var unique = arr.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i); 

I have updated my table stucture as well and removed value attributes